# How much gravitational lensing do we see from the Milky Way?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter, galaxies, gravitational-lensing, milky-way

I assume that the Milky Way has a dark matter halo just like any other. If that is the case, if we look at a huge part of our own galaxy, do we actually see the gravitational lensing effect? How intense is it?

Comment: Are you familiar with the shell theorem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem

Comment: Oh. So we cannot actually see any effect in our own galaxy from our point of view?

Comment: Pretty much. There's a tiny bit of deflection (& Doppler shifting) from the mass of the galactic core, for light trajectories that pass by the core, but we don't get an effect from the bulk of the halo because we're inside it.